# 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict' error in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, runtime-error, pymongo

I'm very new to pymongo. In the following code,

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(DB_HOST,DB_USR,DB_PWD,DB_NAME)
cursor = db.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE userid = \"%s\"" % (table, userID) 
cursor.execute(query)
colNames = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
rows = cursor.fetchall()
objects_list = []
# The below logic makes JSON objet based on fetch MySQL rows.
for row in rows:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    index = 0
    for col in colNames:
        d[col] = row[index]
        index = index + 1
    objects_list.append(d)
return objects_list
```

I'm getting the error,

```
trngl_advertise_perfm
trngl_advertise_activity
trngl_user_fblike
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "IngestDataToMongo.py", line 83, in <module>
userData = getData(user[0], TABLES[i]) # Get data of each user.
File "IngestDataToMongo.py", line 51, in getData
d = collections.OrderedDict()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'
```

Please tell me, how to remove the error.

Comment: @InbarRose I can't change my python version because the code is in script which runs on server. So is there any option like importing a file or other things that I can use instead of OrderedDict.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using Python 2.6 or earlier. `OrderedDict` was not added to Python until version 2.7.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> *New in version 2.7.*

You could use [this backport](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693-ordered-dictionary-for-py24/) instead (also available from [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict)), it'll work on python versions 2.4 and up, or install python 2.7 and run your script with that version instead.

Comment: There is also an ``ordereddict`` package available on PyPI, which probably contains the same code.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: indeed, it links to the recipe from the PyPI page. Thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, I'm really new to python, so I will try updating my python to 2.7 first, it seems simpler to me than other options

Comment: @WhyandHow: If you have `pip` or `easy_install` installed already, it's easy to use those tools to install the version packaged and available on PyPI. That said, it might be that there are *other* things in the `pymongo` package that also require Python 2.7. Upgrading to that python version may well be easier for you in the long run.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now, the problem is I can't install python2.7, because  I run the script using putty on server where I can't change things. So is there any file or code which I can import so it will work, Or is there any option to OrderdDict in older python versions?

Comment: @WhyandHow: Yes, install the backport as a module on the server. A `ordereddict.py` module next to the script will suffice. Then, instead of `from collections import OrderedDict` you can do `from ordereddict import OrderedDict`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks but I can't do that also, because the server is not in my company rather it is in clients company so I can't do changes in it :( or can't install anything on it. So please tell me, is there any other option

Comment: @WhyandHow: Copy the whole OrderedDict definition into your script, remove the `from .. import OrderedDict` line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, thanks; i will try this and come back here